# Python word cloud - IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, word-cloud

I am trying to build wordcloud using dictionary of words in python. 
here is my script

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud 
words = {'Python':15, 'Pandas':13, 'R':16, 'Analyis':10, 'Scikit learn':19, 'Matplotlib':10}
wc = WordCloud()
wcloud = wc.generate_from_frequencies(words)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(wcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

I am getting error like

```
    wcloud = wc.generate_from_frequencies(words)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py", line 263, in generate_from_frequencies
    frequencies = sorted(frequencies, key=item1, reverse=True)

IndexError: string index out of range
```

can someone please help me how to fix this. 
I am able to generate wordcloud for a text file. But i want to pass custom word frequencies in python dictionary (example shown in above script)

I'm running on Windows 7, Anaconda Python 3.5, using Idlex and spyder IDE

Answer (score 2):

From the [`wordcloud` docs](http://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html#wordcloud.WordCloud.generate_from_frequencies):

> static `generate_from_frequencies(frequencies)`
>
> Create a word_cloud from words and frequencies.
>
> **Parameters:**    `frequencies` : array of *tuples*

`frequencies` is supposed to be a list of tuples and you are passing in a dictionary.

Change

```
wcloud = wc.generate_from_frequencies(words)
```

to

```
wcloud = wc.generate_from_frequencies(list(words.items()))
```

**Note:**  This answer applies to the `wordcloud` version 1.2.1.  [On 22 October 2016 the code was changed](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/commit/15d4923a1ce0907fd40359b3927e0fecb8c08e09) in the current master branch on Github.  This yet to be released version (2.0?) changes the data type of `frequencies` from `tuple` to `dict`.  (The OP's code would have run correctly in the new version.)

Here is the updated docstring:

```
def generate_from_frequencies(self, frequencies, max_font_size=None):
    """Create a word_cloud from words and frequencies.

    Parameters
    ----------
    frequencies : dict from string to float
        A contains words and associated frequency.

    max_font_size : int
        Use this font-size instead of self.max_font_size

    Returns
    -------
    self

    """
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, this has been changed in the current master branch on GitHub.

Comment: @MadPhysicist:  Thanks.  I updated the answer so hopefully it doesn't mislead future readers.